# Auto resize tkinter window to fit all widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to have a dynamic sizing for the main tkinter window so that when you add a new widget, you don't have to go change the size of the window. Instead, the main window will account for that widget size and automatically increase its height/width to fit that widget in the window.

```
masterWindow = Tk()

#Main Window min width
self.window_width = screen_width * .01
self.window_height = screen_height * .04

#Window startst in center of screen
self.window_start_x = (screen_width/2)
self.window_start_y = (screen_height/2)
masterWindow.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (self.window_width, self.window_height, self.window_start_x, self.window_start_y))
self.buttonsFrame.pack(side = TOP)
button_width = 13
button_height = 2

#A simple dict that stores script name strings
for script in SCRIPTS.keys():
    #Remove script extension
    script_name = script.split(".")[0]
    button_width = 13
    button_height = 2
    BUTTONS[script] = Button(self.buttonsFrame, text = script, width = button_width, height = button_height, justify = LEFT, wraplength = 100, command = lambda s = script: self.runScript(s))
    BUTTONS[script].grid(row = self.row, column = self.col)
    self.update()

    #Increment row and col and set new window size
    if self.col == 2:
        self.col = 0
        self.row += 1
        reached_max_width = True
    else:
        self.col += 1
        if not reached_max_width:
            self.window_width += button_width * 13
    self.window_height = self.buttonsFrame.winfo_height() * (self.row*3)
    masterWindow.geometry("%dx%d" % (self.window_width, self.window_height))


def runScript(self, script):
    print(script)
```

Comment: Frames will expand automatically. Can you post some code so we can solve your specific problem?

Comment: Tkinter pretty much does that automatically if you use `pack` and/or `grid`, and let tkinter decide on the size of the window. Can you show us a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you are having?

Comment: That code isn't nearly enough. We need to know what `runScript` does, and we need to see enough code to run your code. There's probably something in your code that is preventing the window from resizing, but there's no way to know without seeing a _small_ working program.

Comment: There you go. Let me know if you want something else. I tried using `pack()` for the buttons within the Frame, but that didn't increase the window size, so I took this route, of getting the height of the frame and setting the window size again. This is a hack, however, that i don't want to do.

Comment: The code won't run. It's missing an import statement, the indentation is wrong, and you're using a variable named `screen_width` and `screen_height` without defining it first. Plus, you use `self` but you haven't defined a  class. There are many other problems.

Comment: When you set the window size, you prevent it from auto resizeing.

Comment: It's a big project with lots of code, and I didn't recreate a smaller script that would work since there's a lot of components going into this. Sorry, but I located the issue. Thanks

Comment: @ArtemisFowl I saw that as I was trying to make another working script for here. Thanks man! I appreciate your help! I never would've thought that would cause it to stop resizing.

Comment: @BryanOakley technicaly `self` doesn't have to be used inside a class, it is just a variable that conventionaly refers to the class it is used in.

Comment: @ArtemisFowl: yes, I know. But it looks pretty clear that this was designed to work inside a class.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I don't disagree; I was being pedantic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are explicitly setting the window to a specific size with this line of code:

```
masterWindow.geometry("%dx%d" % (self.window_width, self.window_height))
```

Because you're doing that, tkinter will keep the window to that size even when you add widgets. If you want it to auto-size you need to remove that line of code.

Also, if the user resizes the window, tkinter will try to honor that size. If you want it to automatically resize when adding new widgets you'll need to remove the window size so that tkinter can compute it. You can do that by calling `masterWindow.geometry("")`.

Comment: I left the `self.window_start_x` & `self.window_start_y` in my answer because I actually wanted to define where the window would appear. But this is correct. Removing the definition of the window size made the window dynamically resize itself when a widget is added.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue. The problem was that I was setting an initial Width/Height for the Tkinter `mainWindow` in the block of code:

```
#Main Window min width
self.window_width = screen_width * .01
self.window_height = screen_height * .04
masterWindow.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (self.window_width, self.window_height, self.window_start_x, self.window_start_y))
```

I removed that size definition and setting from the geometry so the code looks like this, and it worked:

```
masterWindow.geometry("+%d+%d" % (self.window_start_x, self.window_start_y))
```

Now the window resizes automatically to account for all the buttons.